# How do arcade buttons work?

Tags: voltage, pcb, switches

(Disclaimer: I'm very very new to this, so forgive if my wording isn't correct)

I'm trying to understand how the wiring of arcade buttons work.

I understand how a button like this works (voltage is carried to the input pin):
[image]

But I don't understand how a button like this works, where there is no power connection. The button is just connected to the input pin and ground. Does the current come from the input pin itself? But then wouldn't it just go straight through to ground? How does the button actually activate anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the schematic of your switch circuit R1 is either on the board or in the case of a microcontroller it can be programmed to be on the pin internally.

When the switch is open the resistor pulls up the voltage on Vin to very close to the supply.

When you close the switch Vin is pulled down to 0V. The resistor is conducting a constant current given by I=V/R. This allows Vin to be pulled down without creating any sort of 'short circuit'.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2B4tl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The pulling resistors (more likely pull up than pull down) are located on the circuit board, so the switch merely needs to make the connection to the other rail (ground) or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the buttons. They both close the two contacts when it is pushed.

The pull-ups are on board. You can do the same with Arduino, set the pin as input with internal pull-up. The button will only need two wires, ground and input.